# Draggable elements inside of a carousel

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slick.js

I am working with slick carousel and would like to make elements drag-and-droppable between slides. I am running into a problem when trying to drag an element to the next set of slides, when the carousel animation occurs, the dragged element "slides" with the carousel instead of remaining pinned under the cursor. Ideally the element would remain pinned under the cursor until the carousel animation finishes so that the user can select which of the newly visible slides to drop the element onto but I'm open to any other ideas that would make this more fluid.

Here is how I am triggering the carousel to slide:

```
$(".can-drag").sortable({
    connectWith: ".can-drag",
    containment: $(".slider"),
    sort: function(e, ui) {
      var draggedElementLeftSide = $(draggedElement).offset().left;
      var draggedElementRightSide = draggedElementLeftSide + $(draggedElement).outerWidth();

      var containerLeftSide = $('#container').offset().left;
      var containerRightSide = containerLeftSide + $('#container').outerWidth();

     if (draggedElementLeftSide <= containerLeftSide) {
         var currentSlide = $('.slider').slick('slickCurrentSlide');
         if (currentSlide >= 4) {
             $(draggedElement).draggable({
                 disabled: true
             });
          $('.slider').slick('slickSetOption', 'speed', 2000, true);
          $('.slider').slick('slickGoTo', currentSlide - 4);
         }
    } 

    else if (draggedElementRightSide >= containerRightSide) {
        $('.slider').slick('slickSetOption', 'speed', 2000, true);
        var currentSlide = $('.slider').slick('slickCurrentSlide');
        $('.slider').slick('slickGoTo', currentSlide + 4);
    }
},
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hotr8x1f/5/ - Try dragging a 2016 item to the far right.

Comment: I do notice some anomalies with your code such as multiple `var currentSlide ` declarations (why not just one before the `if`? As well as `$(draggedElement)` when it is already a jQuery object and thus simply `draggedElement` would suffice.  I am not super familiar with `slick` and thus have not been able to determine the change you desire.

Comment: I did not that at times "dragged" elements will loose the ability to maintain a drag-able capability once dropped, not consistent but a periodical circumstance.

Comment: The sort function gets called repeatedly while an element is being dragged so I figured it would save some overhead not determining the current slide until the carousel is actually going to shift the slide set. As for,  $(draggedElement), just bad habit I suppose.

Comment: I wonder perhaps if you might instead utilize the `start: function(e, ui) {
      console.log('start');
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      console.log('stop');
    },` rather than the `sort:` here to better effect? Just a thought. Or perhaps all three.